# Conditional Gitlab-ci Tags

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm fairly certain I already know the answer, and this is just me just confirming really.

There is no way of making `tags` in the gitlab-ci conditional is there?

Essentially to avoid duplication I want to have a gitlab-ci job that can push to certain AWS ECR instances contained in different accounts, so lets say Non-Production and Production.

We essentially have different runners for each, so on the job I want to push to Non-Production I would have:

```
tags:
  - Non-Production
```

and then I would have this for Production:

```
tags:
  - Production
```

I know I could have 2 jobs and then just use Rules and have a base Job, but I was wondering if I could have the condition as part of the `tags` part itself, something like this using the `CI_ENVIRONMENT_TIER`:

```
tags:
  - if: '$CI_ENVIRONMENT_TIER == "production"'
    then: Production
  - if: '$CI_ENVIRONMENT_TIER == "testing"'
    then: Non-Production
```

Like I say I'm fairly confident in that no this does not exist, but you never know I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the CI workflow keyword to define variables depending on certain conditions. The tags keyword supports CICD variables so doesnt need to be static.

```yaml
---
variables:
  RUNNER_TAG: "default"
  SOME_FLAG: "foo"
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $SOME_FLAG == "bar"
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "bar-runner"  
    - if: $SOME_FLAG == "baz"
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "baz-runner"              
    - when: always              

sample_job:
    tags:
        - $RUNNER_TAG
    script:
        - echo "using $RUNNER_TAG"
```

However you couldnt use the CI_ENVIRONMENT_TIER since thats job specific and not known until the job runs. And for the job to run you need to have selected a runner. So its a catch 22 situation, but you could make use of another var to act as the flag for the workflow rules

Comment: This certainly does sound like something that may work for me, I'll give it a go after the weekend when back in work and get back to you.