# Use different CI runner tags for main project and forks in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

Can I use different CI runners (per tags) depending on GitLab CI variables? In pseudo code I'm looking for something like this:

```yaml
default:
  tags:
    - $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE == "foo" ? "private" : "public"
```

**Context**

I have two different sets of CI runners available in my self-hosted GitLab instance:

- Low performant and unstable CI runners globally with tag `public`
- High performant and reliable CI runners in the group of my project with tag `private`

The project has an internal visibility and is expected to be forked to personal namespace.

My goal is to use the high performant and reliable CI runners with `private` tag if available. But fallback to the low performant and unstable CI runners with `public` tag if the other once are not available.

I know I could use anchors or extends to define the steps and reuse them across to different jobs like this:

```yaml
.test: &test
  script:
    - echo "hello world"

test-with-private-runners:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE == "foo"
  tags:
    - private
  <<: *test

test-with-public-runners:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE != "foo"
  tags:
    - public
  <<: *test
```

I fear the complexity of that approach and wonder if there is a more simple alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the tags a variable. You can set this variable conditionally using `workflow:rules:variables:`. You can use a conditional rule based on the project ID, path, or namespace, for example:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    # replace with your actual source project namespace
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE == "my-namespace" 
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "private"
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE != "my-namespace"
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "public"


default:
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
```

The same thing can also be done on a per-job basis using `job:tags:` and/or `job:rules:variables:`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is conditional tags.

Fortunately, your conditional can be expressed using a builtin variable: `CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE`

Now, to convert this into a conditional tag, the trick is to use [`rules` with `include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-rules-with-include).

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
.job_tags:
  tags:
    - public

# The include with override .job_tags if you are in the "foo" namespace
include:
  - local: foo-tags.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE == "foo"

hello_world:
  extends: .job_tags
  script:
    - echo "Hello World"
```

**foo-tags.yml**:

```
.job_tags:
  tags:
    - private
```

Note 1:
I chose to present the compact implementation, where the default `tags` section is conditionally overridden by the included one. However you could have a maybe more readable implementation with two includes, each covering one case.

Note 2:
It looks like you could also use `workflow` per this answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77159730/22907359.